# Getting simple ArcGIS Python toolbox parameters to be enabled or disabled on load

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, tool-validation

I am attempting to get a simple ArcGIS Python toolbox (pyt) set up that allows me to present a subset of appropriate parameters based on selection from a 'parent' parameter.  There are 7 (0-6) total in the list object `self.params`.

`self.params[0]` is a `ValueList` containing `Selection A`, `Selection B`, and `Selection C`.  It should be the only parameter enabled at load time.

If the user selects `Selection A`, `self.params[1]` and `self.params[2]` are enabled.  If the user selects `Selection B`, `self.params[3]` and `self.params[4]` are enabled; and so on.

Unfortunately this is one of those cases where "read the docs" is a little tricky because I have not found a case where Esri shows a full .pyt with this sort of logic, showing how it all should fit together.  After reading the pertinent documentation I've attempted to come up with the following code, however, at run-time it is:

- Loading all parameters and seeming to ignore the `initializeParameters()` method,
- Yielding a `TypeError` because I am giving "two" arguments where only one is accepted (probably me misunderstanding how the class object is supposed to behave in a Python toolbox).

code:

```
import arcpy


class Toolbox(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of
        the .pyt file).
        """
        self.label = "ArcTesting"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [TestValidation]


class TestValidation(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class).
        """
        self.label = "TestValidation"
        self.description = "Test tool validation logic."
        self.canRunInBackground = False
        self.params = self.getParameterInfo()

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """
        Define parameters.
        :return: list
        """
        # First parameter (Default Enabled)
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Choice 1",
            name="input_choice_1",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        # Set up the first parameter's value list
        param0.filter.type = "ValueList"
        param0.filter.list = ["Selection A", "Selection B", "Selection C"]

        # Second parameter (Default Disabled)
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Layer A",
            name="input_layer_a",
            datatype="GPLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        # Third Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input String A",
            name="input_string_a",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        # Fourth Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Layer B",
            name="input_layer_b",
            datatype="GPLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        # Fifth Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input String B",
            name="input_string_b",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        # Sixth Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param5 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Layer C",
            name="input_layer_c",
            datatype="GPLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        # Seventh Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param6 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input String C",
            name="input_string_c",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )

        params = [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def initializeParameters(self):
        self.params[0].enabled = True
        for p in self.params[1:]:
            p.enabled = False
        return

    def updateParameters(self):
        """Modify the values/properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a
        parameter has been changed."""
        if self.params[0].valueAsText == "Selection A":
            for p in self.params[1:2]:
                p.enabled = True
        elif self.params[0].valueAsText == "Selection B":
            for p in self.params[3:4]:
                p.enabled = True
        elif self.params[0].valueAsText == "Selection C":
            for p in self.params[5:]:
                p.enabled = True

    def updateMessages(self):
        """Modify messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter. This method is called after internal validation."""
        return True

    def execute(self):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        self.initializeParameters()
        self.updateParameters()
```

Comment: I'd try 3 parameters only, redefining ast 2 depending on value picked in first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `execute` is called when you click the run button, not when the tool loads.
- Set params 1-6 `enabled = False` in `getParameterInfo` initially.
- `getParameterInfo` is called automatically, don't call it yourself
- `updateParameters` and `updateMessages` are passed a positional `parameters` argument by ArcGIS, your method `def` needs to accept this. You don't return the params, just set them, because of the way python passes arguments by reference.
- You don't need to set the params as instance variables, i.e `self.params`.
- You should set uneeded params `.enabled=False` when changing `params[0]`.
- python slices exclude the upper bound, so in your `updateParameters` you need to use `params[1:3]` to access `param[1]` and `param[2]` and `params[3:5]` to access `param[3]` and `param[4]`  etc...
- Python toolbox (*.pyt) tools don't have an `initializeParameters` method.  This is only for [`ToolValidator` classes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/customizing-script-tool-behavior.htm) which you only use in [script tools](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm) in a custom toolbox (*.tbx)

Example:

```
import arcpy


class Toolbox(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of
        the .pyt file).
        """
        self.label = "ArcTesting"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [TestValidation]


class TestValidation(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class).
        """
        self.label = "TestValidation"
        self.description = "Test tool validation logic."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """
        Define parameters.
        :return: list
        """
        # First parameter (Default Enabled)
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Choice 1",
            name="input_choice_1",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )
        # Set up the first parameter's value list
        param0.filter.type = "ValueList"
        param0.filter.list = ["Selection A", "Selection B", "Selection C"]

        # Second parameter (Default Disabled)
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Layer A",
            name="input_layer_a",
            datatype="GPLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param1.enabled = False

        # Third Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input String A",
            name="input_string_a",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param2.enabled = False

        # Fourth Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Layer B",
            name="input_layer_b",
            datatype="GPLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param3.enabled = False

        # Fifth Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input String B",
            name="input_string_b",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param4.enabled = False

        # Sixth Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param5 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Layer C",
            name="input_layer_c",
            datatype="GPLayer",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param5.enabled = False

        # Seventh Parameter (Default Disabled)
        param6 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input String C",
            name="input_string_c",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Optional",
            direction="Input"
        )
        param6.enabled = False

        params = [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, params):
        """Modify the values/properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a
        parameter has been changed."""
        if params[0].valueAsText == "Selection A":
            for p in params[1:3]:
                p.enabled = True
            for p in params[3:]:
                p.enabled = False
        elif params[0].valueAsText == "Selection B":
            for p in params[3:5]:
                p.enabled = True
            for p in params[1:3] + params[5:]:
                p.enabled = False
        elif params[0].valueAsText == "Selection C":
            for p in params[5:]:
                p.enabled = True
            for p in params[1:5]:
                p.enabled = False

    def updateMessages(self, params):
        """Modify messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter. This method is called after internal validation."""
        return True

    def execute(self):
        pass
```

The `updateParameters` method could be made a bit clearer by using a dictionary:

```
def updateParameters(self, params):
    """Modify the values/properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a
    parameter has been changed."""
    lookup = {
        "Selection A": [1, 2],  # Params to enable
        "Selection B": [3, 4],
        "Selection C": [5, 6]
    }
    enabled = lookup[params[0].valueAsText]
    for i, p in enumerate(params[1:], start=1):
        if i in enabled:
            p.enabled = True
        else:
            p.enabled = False
```

Comment: Thanks - so I don't know if this is beyond the scope of my initial question but, what's then the use for `initializeParameters()`?  Only dependencies?  Because the Esri docs seem particularly slender on that method.  Either way, your suggestion worked and I have a better grasp of it now.

Comment: Python toolbox (*.pyt) tools don't have an initializeParameters method, see last dotpoint (edit)